# Spring Boot JPA: @Modifying @Query has no effect

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm trying to increase performance by executing one request instead of updating each entity. The sql looks right and the call to this method is executed but I see no "update" executed in hibernate log.

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Order x SET x.reservedByClient = :value WHERE x.tourId = :id")
public void updateReservationStatus(@Param("value") Boolean value, @Param("id") Long id);
```

Any hints where to look ?

Comment: Arnie Schwarzvogel.
just as the solution offered by Dvorog.
the anotation "@Transactional" should be added.
and you can try to solve the problem by yourself depend on the exeception log, in this case, i bet that you have received the log such as Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query",

Answer (score 2):

Modifiying queries should be wrapped in a transaction. Try adding `@Transactional` to the query.

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Order x SET x.reservedByClient = :value WHERE x.tourId = :id")
@Transactional
public void updateReservationStatus(@Param("value") Boolean value, @Param("id") Long id);
```

Comment: @Transactional will be used in the service layer. can we use in the repository level . correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: `@Transactional` can be used in both layers (service and repository). It depends on what you want to do.